# Whats the Interface between a Postfix server and a Mail Program?

Tags: email, postfix, thunderbird

I set up a postfix server and he works. I can send and get mails. As long as I send mails in bash over ssh on the server. But how do I send and get mails from a mail program e.g. Thunderbird.

I know it's a amateur question but I dont get it.

Comment: IMAP or POP for incoming mails (-> Postfix) and SMTP for outgoing mails (Dovecot).

Comment: postfix is primarily an SMTP server, so it's what speaks SMTP with your mail program. To fetch email, you don't go through postfix at all, but usually through an IMAP server, i.e. a different program running on your mail server.

Comment: also, I feel like we should probably stress this: make *very* sure that your postfix only sends emails from SMTP users who've successfully authenticated. Otherwise, your mail server becomes an *open relay*, i.e. anyone can use it to send large amount of spam. You don't want that! a) you then become part of the global spam sources and hurt everyone else, b) your mail server ends up very quickly on block lists and becomes effectively unable to send emails to most people – receiving mail servers will just deny.

Comment: (I know this sounds kind of mean, but "I've set up an SMTP server, but I don't know what protocol my mail program is using to talk to a mail server" doesn't bode well. You might really want to read up a bit at least on the basics of how "email" works; in the case of mail servers, it can really save you *a lot* of trouble to know, in the bigger picture, what you're doing.)